# Magento remove items from cart at loggin out

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to clear or remove all items from cart after logout user.
I found this but I don't know where I have to put it exactly

```
foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works

app/etc/modules/Amir_Meta.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amir_Meta>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Amir_Meta>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Amir/Meta/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amir_Meta>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Amir_Meta>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <amir_meta>
                <class>Amir_Meta/Observer</class>
            </amir_meta>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <customer_logout><!-- event observer -->
                <observers>
                    <amir_meta>
                        <class>amir_meta/observer</class>
                        <method>Clean_cart</method>
                    </amir_meta>
                </observers>
            </customer_logout>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Amir/Meta/Model/Observer.php

```
     <?php

class Amir_Meta_Model_Observer {

public function Clean_cart(Varient_Event_Observer $observer) {

        foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an observer for "customer_logout" event.

[Answer here describe how to create observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-catalog-product-save-before)

You just need to use "customer_logout" instead of "catalog_product_save_before".

Comment: it does not work ! I did this but he never empty my cart when I disconnect when i click on disconnect

Comment: In config.xml you posted  try changing <class>amir_meta/observer</class> to <class>Amir_Meta_Model_Observer</class>

Comment: No, i think that the xml is good, I changed the observer and now it works. Thank you!

I will correct my post

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me:

in /app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Cleancart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Cleancart>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
            <Mage_Catalog />
      </depends>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Cleancart>
  </modules>
</config>
```

in /app/code/local/Mycompany/Cleancart/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Cleancart>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Cleancart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mycompany_cleancart>
                <class>Mycompany_Cleancart_Model</class>
            </mycompany_cleancart>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_logout><!-- event observer -->
                <observers>
                    <Mycompany_Cleancart>
                        <class>mycompany_cleancart/observer</class>
                        <method>cleancart</method>
                    </Mycompany_Cleancart>
                </observers>
            </customer_logout>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

in /app/code/local/Mycompany/Cleancart/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Mycompany_Cleancart_Model_Observer {

    public function cleancart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ){
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();

        }
    }
}
```